# Não ajustar menu quando submenu aparecer

Tags: css, flexbox

Estou iniciando com o flexbox, gostaria de fazer um menu que não fique ajustando a largura quando os submenus aparecem:

```css
/* Navigation - menu style */
nav ul {
    padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    flex-direction: column;
}
nav > ul {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
nav > ul, nav > ul > li, nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
    display: flex;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Usuários
            <ul>
                <li>Conectar</li>
                <li>Cadastrar</li>
                <li>Meu perfil</li>
                <li>ITEM MUITO LARGO</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>UFEF</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Tentei algumas coisas, mas sem sucesso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bastava adicionar a propriedade `flex` nos menus. Para manter o alinhamento das palavras no centro adicionar `text-align: center;`:

```css
/* Navigation - menu style */
nav ul {
    padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}
nav > ul {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
nav > ul > li {
    flex: 1;
}
nav > ul, nav > ul > li, nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
    display: flex;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Usuários
            <ul>
                <li>Conectar</li>
                <li>Cadastrar</li>
                <li>Meu perfil</li>
                <li>ITEM MUITO LARGO</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>UFEF</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```